# Weird numbers and symbols in front of command in terminal with alias zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, alias

I have tried my best to explain clearly in the title. So basically have this alias command in my .zshrc file

```
alias "zsh=zsh | lolcat -a"
```

and I have to say it works. But if I do any command, lets say `brew -v`, weird numbers and symbols appear like this:

```
➜  ~ zsh
38;5;49m38;5;148m38;5;184m38;5;184m38;5;184mbrew -v
38;5;199m38;5;199mHomebrew 3.1.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 5a867203bc; last commit 2021-04-14)
38;5;178m38;5;214m38;5;214m38;5;214m
```

I have al those 38;5;178m38;5;214m38;5;214m38;5;214m and it is very annoying
How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Seems to be "formatting" like coloring etc that went wrong. Did you attempt something related to that?

Comment: @BrandonLi : `lolcat` inserts colour codes everywhere, even in the middle of escape sequences with other purposes. For your usage of `zsh`, I suggest that you restrict your PS1 to something less fancy. Also, don't do any other explicit colorization, in particular, don't allow `git` or `brew` to colorize its output. You can't  serve two (colour-) masters at the same time ;-)